# How to use Javascript timeout to apply jQuery addClass

Tags: jquery, settimeout, jquery-events

Here is my entire document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  .highlighted { color:green; font-weight:bold; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {


function itemHighlight(n) 
{
      $(function() {
        $("ul > li:eq("+n+")").addClass("highlighted"); 
      });
}

NumofLi = $('li').length;

for(i = 0; i < NumofLi; i++) {
    var timeoutvar = $("ul > li:eq("+i+")").attr('data-time');
    setTimeout("itemHighlight("+i+")", timeoutvar);
}


});

</script>

</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li data-time="4000">foo</li>
    <li data-time="5000">foo</li>
    <li data-time="9000">foo</li>
    <li data-time="11000">foo</li>
    <li data-time="15000">foo</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like the li's to have the class "highlighted" added after their corresponding 'data-time' milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('li').map(function(){
        var _this = $(this);
        setTimeout(function(){
            _this.addClass('highlighted');
        },Number(_this.data('time')));
    });
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/dzAGn/2/

Comment: Ya there were a few things I noticed, like you were passing your `itemHighlight` function as a string into your setTimeout to be `eval()`'d, and you lost scope on your `i` so it was always the max value (5), so the only one that would work is the 15 second `li`.  I also noticed you're using JQuery 1.3.2, and it's on 1.6.2 - a LOT has improved since then. Time to upgrade, friend :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    #("ul li")each(function()
    {
        var timeOut = Number( $(this).attr("data-time") );
        var element = $(this);

        setTimeout(function()
        {
            element.addClass('highlighted');
        },  timeOut);
    });
});
```

Comment: setTimeOut needs to be setTimeout

Comment: @redsquare: Sorry, a typo, fixed now. Thank you for noticing it :-).

Answer (score 0):

Your functions is inside `$(document).ready(...)`. Put it outside:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    NumofLi = $('li').length;
    for(i = 0; i < NumofLi; i++) {
        var timeoutvar = $("ul > li:eq("+i+")").attr('data-time');
        setTimeout("itemHighlight("+i+")", timeoutvar);
    }
});

function itemHighlight(n) {
    $(function() {
        $("ul > li:eq("+n+")").addClass("highlighted"); 
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YaPXn/) example

```
$(function(){

    $('li').each(function(){
        var _this = $(this);
        setTimeout($.proxy(timeout, _this), Number(_this.data('time')));
    });

    function timeout(){
        this.addClass('highlighted')
    }

});
```